# cookieless authentication in php5

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookieless

In my PHP application, I used UserName & Pwd and check the user table in the database to check  the validity of users.  After the login is successful, I stored the credentials in the Server Session as below:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['pwd'] = $pwd;
```

And I checked the session to ensure that the user has already logged in.  You can see the code below:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['userId']))
    header("Location: login.php");
```

The problem is if I disabled the cookie in the browser, I could not go into another page even though the log in is successful.  I found out that, the PHP session uses the cookie to store some values in the browser.  Is there anyway to use cookieless session in PHP5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to append the `sessid` or `sid` to every link.

It's described in detail here:
http://myles.eftos.id.au/blog/2005/11/26/cookie-less-sessions-in-php/

You also need to change `php.ini` like so: `php_value session.use_trans_sid = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you don't want to.  In fact, you should *only* use cookie-based sessions.  This is the default configuration as of PHP 5.3.  Please read up on [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) for more information.

What circumstances do you have that force you to require users be able to use your site without cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, by enabling `session.use_trans_sid`.  However, there's security concerns with doing so.

It's generally accepted that in order to login, one needs to accept a cookie.

The other alternative is to use http authorisation instead of sessions, though this also has it's drawbacks.

See [session id passing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a session id, and add it to your links like this

```
<?php
session_start();
$session_id = session_id();
header('Location: http://www.test.com/?sess_id='. $session_id);
?>
```

Comment: You have to handle this in your login.php like this
if(!empty($_GET['sess_id']))
{
//code is it the admin?
}